# Ionic continuous scroll

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a way to implement a text continuous scroll

Basically, I would like to have an in-line text with time table for the next boat departures, and I would like to scroll it horizontally, both ways and continuously, like a carousel.

[image]

Is it possible ? How shall I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Directive `<ion-scroll >` works for scrolling .

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="x" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
      </ion-scroll>
```

Take a look of this http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/xGWBja

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've managed to do like in your example but i'm trying to remove the "walls" of the scroll and make it continuous

Answer (score 0):

You can check my codepen, not perfect but maybe it will be helpfull.
http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/bZjjRg

The thing is to use ion-infinite-scroll with ion-scroll or ion-content. Sth like this

```
<ion-content class="padding" >
  <ion-scroll direction="x" class="item">
    <div ng-repeat="scrollItem in scrollItems" class="scroll-item">     
      <strong>{{ scrollItem.id }}</strong> 
      <hr />
      <span>{{ scrollItem.index }}</span> 
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
  <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="load()" distance="20%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

In this case when scroll will be 20% from the end, the load function will be fired so new data can be loaded. Here I do it with dummy function that adds new items to scrollItems list.

```
$scope.load = function() {
  var previousLength = $scope.scrollItems.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.scrollItems.push({ 
      id: Math.random() * 1000,
      index: previousLength + i + 1
    });
  }
  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
};
```

And once the data is loaded there is an event broadcasted, to refresh scroll. `$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');`

Check also ionic scroll documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/. There will be an explanation on ion-infinite-scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I will look after your code to try and make it work as I want ! Thanks !